# What to do with question that was supposed to be self-answered, but stalled?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/99961/16495

Due to huge workload and personal issues I wasn't able to write good answer yet. And I will not be able to do so tomorrow. Should I leave it be? I admit it does not show my own attempts etc as it should...

Or should I delete it, and undelete once I'm ready to post my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say

- Remove the comment noting you're going to answer it
- Leave it open
- Come back and answer it when you're ready, *if an identical solution hasn't already been proposed by someone else*.

As for not showing your own attempts, I don't think that matters. It's a well structured question, and it's obvious enough you're familiar with the problem domain. I guess you could solve this particular problem at both the server and app level, so including every possible attempt might get out of hand. Better to leave it more open-ended IMO.

Comment: So be it. Wish me luck.

Comment: Yes, I don't see what else should be done, if not letting other users know you are not going to answer it anytime soon.